# How to use Semantic UI in genexus

Tags: genexus

I'm trying to use the SemanticUI as our CSS framework on Genexus. I followed the instruction here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SHQdwn4LDh0 but the SemanticUI is still not available on Base CSS property.

I'm not sure what went wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options: install it within the GeneXus installation (that will enable it for all the KBs that you use) or install it in a specific KB.

**To install it within GX:**

1. In the GeneXus installation directory (e.g. C:\Program Files (x86)\GeneXus\GeneXus17u4) create a new directory called "CSSLibraries" (use exactly this name)
2. unzip SemanticUI within it.
3. rename the uncompressed directory to SemanticUI
4. Close GX and start it again.

You should end with something like: C:\Program Files (x86)\GeneXus\GeneXus17u4\CSSLibraries\SemanticUI containing:
[image]

Further information (including a sample KB using SemanticUI): https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?39566,KB%3ASemanticUI+Design+System

**To install it in a specific KB:**
Include the SemanticUI.zip into the KB following these rules:

1. Previously rename .zip file as .gxlibrary.
2. The file within the KB must be named with a trailing "_gxlibrary" (e.g. SemanticUI_gxlibrary).

It looks like this:

[image]

Further information:
https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?48729,Base%20Style%20property%20%28Web%20Theme%29%20%28GeneXus%2017%20u4%20and%20prior%29#How+to+create+a+new+Base+Library+inside+a+KB